# Why does the toString Method not work when it is overwritten?

Tags: java, overriding

```
public abstract class Car {
    // This class includes common properties for a car, in this way we wont have to change if we need to add a new car brand
        public String name;
        public String colour;
        public int model;
        public String feature;
        public String getFeature() {
            return feature;
        }
        public void setFeature(String feature) {
            this.feature = feature;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getColour() {
            return colour;
        }
        public void setColour(String colour) {
            this.colour = colour;
        }
        public int getModel() {
            return model;
        }
        public void setModel(int model) {
            this.model = model;
        }   
    }
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
        CarFactory carfactory = new CarFactory();

        System.out.println("Hello, please enter your car brand \n BMW \n MERCEDE \n OPEL");
        Car usercar = null;


        String usertext = input.nextLine();
        usercar = carfactory.makeCar(usertext);
        System.out.println("enter colour of your car");
        usertext = input.nextLine();
        usercar.setColour(usertext);
        System.out.println("enter model of your car");
        usertext =input.nextLine();
        usercar.setModel(Integer.parseInt(usertext));

        System.out.println("Your Car Information;\n "+ usercar.getName()+" \n Colour:" + usercar.getColour() + "\n Model "+ usercar.getModel()+ "\n Your car's plus point is " + usercar.getFeature());

       }
```

The question is, if i want to print car information with toString Metod,  how would it be?  i wrote one in Car class but it didnt work, feature is assign from car's own classes..

here is the my toString metod

```
 public String toString(){
     return "Your Car Information;\n "+ getName()+" \n Colour:" + getColour() + "\n Model "+getModel()+ "\n Your car's plus point is " +getFeature();
 }
```

Comment: Please reformat your code - Indent each code line with at least 4 spaces, otherwise it's barely readable. Also - what exacly do you want the toString() to do?

Comment: "*if i want to print car information with toString Metod, how would it be?*" you simply use `System.our.println(yourCar)`. `println` will internally invoke `toString` method and use its result. It is similar to `System.our.println(yourCar.toString())`

Comment: "*if i want to print car information with toString Metod*" -- Your `toString` method shouldn't print anything. It should simply return a string. If you want to print that string, use `System.out.println(carObject)` as @Pshemo suggests.

Comment: can you explain why it didn't work??

Comment: I want to use toString metod instead System.out.println

Comment: you need to use `System.out.println(usercar);` and write that `toString()` method in your `Car` class.

Comment: ok! i did it now, thanks Pshemo

Comment: In short toString() works just fine, you need to call it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must override `toString()` method of `java.lang.Object` like this:

```
class Car {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Your Car Information;\n " + getName() + " \n Colour:" +
                getColour() + "\n Model " + getModel() + "\n Your car's plus point is " +
                getFeature();
    }
}
```

Secondly, you can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 'CarClass' is a no-abstract class, who extends the 'Car' class
    Car car = new CarClass();
    // the first way
    String information = car.toString();
    System.out.println(information);
    // the second way
    System.out.println(car);
}
```